# Adding a hook for elastic search logging

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logging, kibana, elk

I want to stream all my logs to elastic search. Currently, all my `print` logs are written into the `application.log` file as shown below

```
import logging
import sys


class LogStream(object):

    def __init__(self, logger, log_level = logging.INFO):
        self.logger = logger
        self.log_level = log_level
        self.line = ""

    def write(self, log_string):
        self.logger.log(self.log_level, log_string)

    def flush(self):
        pass


# https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig
# https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html
# https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

logging.basicConfig(
level=logging.DEBUG,
format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s : %(name)s',
)

file_formatter=logging.Formatter(
    '{"time":"%(asctime)s", "message": "%(message)s", "name": "%(name)s", \
    "level": "%(levelname)s"}'
)


logger_name = ""
# Setup the info logger stream ##
info_file_handler=logging.FileHandler("application.log")
info_file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
stdout_logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
stdout_logger.addHandler(info_file_handler)
sys.stdout = LogStream(stdout_logger, logging.INFO)
```

So now, if I do:

```
print("Task A was completed")
```

it creates a log entry into `application.log`. I want to add a hook, such that when the `print` statement gets called, it also streams the log to `elastic search`. How could I do this? I could not enough documentation and examples around this.

Answer (score 1):

Just install on your server some log parsing software.

I recommend [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/download).

- It will read this file
- It will parse it the way you tell fluentd to. (using regex)
- It will send to elastic search each line as a document.

Comment: Isn't there a way with code? I have done with nodejs using Winston but for python, I have not found an easy to use solution

Comment: Technically ElasticSearch has a very simple REST api. So issue a HTTP request for each line from log directly to your elastic might work. It wouldn’t be very professional, but if you are interested in this approach we can discuss this. as a starting point I would suggest [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) to simplify the network requests part.

Comment: My python script sends a lot of logs. Is there a better way than sending HTTP requests? Is there no streaming solution or a way where I can just add a hook and let the native logging module handle everything on print function?